# How does __() decide which language to use (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, localization

I'm using `__("english text", "textdomain")` in a WordPress theme template.

The base language of the site is English.

I've successfully added a .pot file for German.

If I set the language in Settings, General to German, I get the German translations on the front end no problem.

I'm trying to implement a language selector, so on the front end the site visitor can select a language.

I thought it was just a case of setting the lang attribute in the html tag appropriately. So when the user selects German, I output `<html lang="de-DE">`. But still `__()` uses the language from the WordPress admin settings.

I guess I'm approaching this in the wrong way. Does `__()` only ever use the language set in WP Admin? Or can I force it to use a different translation file depending on what the visitor selects on the front end?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use the WordPress filter locale https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/locale/

You can do something like this in your function.php

```
//set desired locale
add_filter( 'locale', function($locale) {
    if ( !is_admin() ) 
        $locale = "de-DE";
    return $locale;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already tried it. That controls the lang attribute that WP adds to the html tag, but that's just the same as setting the lang attribute manually... the __() function ignores that attribute and uses the language from WP admin settings.

Comment: After further investigation and testing, turns out this answer is correct. Thank you. I also found this answer which helped: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49451/change-locale-manually-at-runtime. And there was a mistake in my code. The locale returned by the filter must use an underscore e.g. de_DE not a dash de-DE. This caught me out because the lang attribute has a dash and I assumed that's what I needed to return from the filter. I guess WP's language_attributes() function is converting the underscore to a dash.